# How to copy the entire folder from one directory to another SAS studio?

Tags: sas, sas-macro, sas-studio

How to create a SAS macro-function that can copy standard work folders based on different project types to the project folder?

Standard work folders are saved in SAS Studio at：

```
%let standard_work_A = "/aaa/standard_work/standard_work_A"
%let standard_worl_B = "/aaa/standard_work/standard_work_B"
```

I want to copy standard_work_A to my project folder.

```
%let project_folder = "aaa/project_1/"
```

Comment: Copy want?  Arbitrary operating system files?  SAS datasets? One directory or subdirectories also?  Does your SAS installation allow you to call operating system commands, what is the setting of the XCMD option?  What operating system is your SAS session running on?

Comment: Have you considered using DATA step git functions? (See https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings20/4197-2020.pdf)